# Ionic Side Menu bar transparent

Tags: css, angular7, ionic4

I develop an app using ionic 4 but I have some trouble.
Because Side bar doesn't change the style with special size.
Please help me.

I tried many times in variable.scss and component.scss, but no changes.

```
Ion-menu {
    transparent: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this code.
This will be work correctly.

```
ion-menu {
  --background: transparent;
  --ion-background-color: transparent;
  --ion-color-base: transparent !important;

  left: 0px;

  ion-toolbar {
    --background: transparent;
  }

  ion-list {
    background: white;
  }

}
```